# Java Bulk WRITE

Tags: java

I have to write a series of characters in the disk file and I want to use bulk writing to reduce disk I/O. Currently, I am using File Writer class. However, it is too slow. Can anybody help me how to perform bulk write in Java like maintaining a large buffer and periodically flush it.

Comment: Have you looked at using NIO?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, you mean CharBuffer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably interested in a [`FileChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html). `Channel`s were designed to perform bulk IO operations to and from [`Buffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html)s.

Ex:

```
FileChannel fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file).getChannel();
fileOut.write(ByteBuffer.wrap("Whatever you want to write".getBytes()));
```

Comment: Actually, I want to maintain a large buffer (whose size I can mention) and periodically flush it.

Comment: @Arpssss You can maintain a `ByteBuffer` and periodically write it to the file system. You don't have to create your `ByteBuffer` inline like that.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use charbuffer of NIO ?

Comment: `FileChannel` cannot write a `CharBuffer`. You can, however, use `ByteBuffer#putChar` to put characters into it.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. I also found another way.

Comment: @Arpssss Actually, you can use a `CharBuffer`. You would just have to use a [`CharsetEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) to convert it to a `ByteBuffer` before writing it to the file.